# Function.apply(x)/.bind(x) results in `this` being `undefined`

Tags: javascript, require

I'm working on getting https://github.com/donmccurdy/expression-eval to properly support expressions containing `this`.

The module defines a function:

```
function evaluate ( node, context ) {
  ...
}
```

It exports it as `eval`:

```
module.exports = {
  parse: jsep,
  eval: evaluate,
  compile: compile
};
```

In my code, I define a local context for `this` and call `expr.eval`:

```
const expr = require( 'expression-eval' );

function test() {

  console.log( this ); // outputs the right thing

  var context = { baz: 'blah' };
  var ast = expr.parse( 'this.A + baz' );
  var val = expr.eval( ast, context );

  console.log( val ); // outputs "undefinedbaz"

}
test.apply( { A: 'aay', B: 'bee } );
```

Inside of `evaluate()` I inserted `console.log( this )`.  Initially, it was the global object.  I added `'use strict';` and it changed to `undefined`.

I've tried everything I can think of to get the value of `this` to have the right value inside of the `evaluate` function:

```
var fn = expr.eval.bind( this );
fn( ast, context );
```

and

```
expr.eval.apply( this, [ ast, context ] );
```

Nothing works.  It's almost as if `require` is doing something BAD which is breaking the ability to use `.apply`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you read the mdn for either method (`apply` or `bind`)? They both accept a parameter where you specify what `this` should be. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Both of your solutions using `bind` and `apply` are correct, but if your `evaluate` function doesn't actually make use of `this`, it won't do anything.

Comment: @chiliNUT - I have read it thoroughly, and googled for hours.  @4castle - the function was modified to explicitly `console.log( this )` and it outputs `undefined`.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/donmccurdy/expression-eval/commit/4e306a17c4de54f2ace60ed92a62c41c098ddc66) does not work. You should pass the thisArgument explicitly (as the zeroth argument) not use the `this` context of `evaluate` - which is `null` in all the recursive evaluation calls.

Comment: @Bergi - sure enough, a simple recursive function loses 'this' also.  Is there a work-around?

Comment: @JohnArrowwood You don't want a workaround, you want to explicitly model property references and method calls in your evaluator.

Comment: @Bergi - this is a module that takes a string, uses jsep to parse it into an abstract syntax tree, and then evaluates that abstract syntax tree in the context of an object, in order to turn it into a value.  So how do you propose that I explicitly model property references and method calls?

Comment: In the evaluation of the AST. The current evaluation model does not adhere to the spec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160985/discussion-between-john-arrowwood-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in JavaScript, whenever you call a function (as opposed to an object method), unless you use `.bind()`, `.call()`, or `.apply()`, the value of `this` is always lost.  Who knew?

The solutions include:

1) in your recursive function, recurse using `.call()`

```
function silly(i) {
  if ( i < 1 ) // do something with this
  else return silly.call( this, i-1 );
}
```

2) wrap your function and save `this` for reference

```
function silly(i) {
  var localThis = this;
  function s(i) {
    if ( i < 1 ) // do something with localThis
    else return s( i-1 );
  }
  return s(i);
}
```